# Log4Net and userSettings combined causing configuration issue

Tags: c#, log4net, settings

I am trying to implement log4net to my project which also has Settings.Default parameters, but I am receiving a "Configuration system failed to initialize" error on the first recall of any system Settings.Default parameter. Can you guys take a look? Thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="Order_Take_3._0.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
    <sectionGroup name="SectionGroupLogger">
      <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversationPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%thread] %level - %message%newline%exception" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <apender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
  </startup>
  <userSettings>
    <Order_Take_3._0.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="AFEWDUS" serializeAs="String">
        <value>681124</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="AFEKMTUS" serializeAs="String">
        <value>681625</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="cloudReminderCountDown" serializeAs="String">
        <value>21</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="orderConfirmationCheckCountDown" serializeAs="String">
        <value>3</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="AFEKMTCa" serializeAs="String">
        <value>0</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="AFEWDCa" serializeAs="String">
        <value>0</value>
      </setting>
    </Order_Take_3._0.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You don't need sectionGroup. You only need section.

Comment: Hmm I though it would be better to keep everything systematic. I can't understand why putting it into a section group can cause a problem but your advice solved my problem. Thank you very much!